# installing MSDN local help for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdn

I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition. I am not getting local help/MSDN.

How can I install the MSDN library locally?

Comment: in my case. after I installed MS Visual Studio, there was a question asking me if I also want to instal MSND. I selected that I want to install int.. so now I have it. you could try to launch setup again and after going trough all the steps, at the end select to add also local help.. I suppose that you forgot to do that the first time. Good Luck!

Comment: was that visual studio 2010 ultimate edition..??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under Help -> Manage Help Settings, there is a wizard that allows you to install local help files.  It has options to install from online source or from disk.